# startActivity does not work on some phones?

Tags: android-intent, android-context, startactivityforresult

I am very new on developing Android apps. I have a strange issue as follows and waiting your help please.

My app has an activity with a recylerview. This means that I have another activity for cardview design  and a adapter class. In this adapter there is a popopupmenu.

When the user clicks a popupmenu item, a startactivity starts accordingly.

I have 3 phones at different android verisons and API levels. 2 of them is working perfectly with my app but the third one doesn't. When I debug the app with problamatic phone, I see that it collapse when the startactivity line processed. The problamatic phone is newer (higher Android version and API levels) then other two phones. So,It is not a version issue I think.

Here is my code in popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener.

```
Intent elgosterme_gecis =new Intent (mContext, showall.class);
                            elgosterme_gecis.putExtra("No",position+1);
                            elgosterme_gecis.putExtra("number",oyuncuSayisi);
                            mContext.startActivity(elgosterme_gecis);
```

Why, the older phones can run this code perfectly while the newer one can't? The problamatic phone has android 9. The other phones which works well has lower versions of Android.

I need your experiences please....

Just for note: Obviously, there are many other startactivity process in my app and all of them works well with all phones. The only problem is the startactivty in adapter in popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener for only one phone...

This is my constractor in adapter for Context

```
public TabelaAdapterClass_rv1adim4(Context mContext, List<TabeladbModellemeClass_rv1adim3> satirlarListesi) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.satirlarListesi = satirlarListesi;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have added following line before starting the activity and the ploblem solved

```
elgosterge_gecis.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I have looked at the documents in develeoper site but need someone to explain me what is that realy doing and why some phones do not need it while others need?